# Bootstrap Datepicker number of months to display

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Someone knows if there are any option to show more than one month in a single row in Bootstrap Datepicker like jQuery UI Datepicker numberOfMonths where it possible to set the number of months to display.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any [option](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/README.md#options) to do that in Bootstrap datepicker; if you want a datepicker to select a range of date take a look at `bootstrap-daterangepicker`

> This date range picker component for Twitter Bootstrap creates a
>   dropdown menu from which a user can select a range of dates. I created
>   it while building the UI for Improvely, which needed a way to select
>   date ranges for reports.

Github project: https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker